# Unable to use tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, deep-learning, anaconda

I installed tensorflow on my mac via pip and I'm using anaconda as my IDE.
when I run the command

`import tensoflow`

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-3-a649b509054f>", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow

 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *

 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)

 ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
 _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
 File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
Reason: image not found


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I also ran `pip list` in my terminal to check if it was installed properly.
It lists all the tensorflow libraries that I have installed. 
[image: Output of pip list]

I'm using Anaconda v1.6.8 and Spyder v3.2.3

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA GPU in your Mac?

Comment: Macs don't have Nvidia GPU, So I don't think using the GPU version will do me any good.So shall I uninstall the tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: Yes, uninstalling `tensorflow-gpu` should fix the problem.

Comment: @mrry uninstalling `tensorflow-gpu` worked but now while importing keras I m getting this error :`File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 271, in find_module
    "not {}".format(type(path)))
  
RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see that you have 2 versions of tensorflow. with (1.1.0) and without (1.3.0) gpu support. But error you are getting is because the gpu libraries are not properly installed.

For `tensorflow-gpu==1.1.0` follow [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/install/install_mac).

Unfortunatelly tensorflow [dropped support for gpu on Mac since v1.2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac), but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744737/tensorflow-mac-os-gpu-support) may help you setup for a higher version.