# Pip can not find tensorflow for python 3.6 on macOS

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am installing tensorflow on a new virtualenvironment. When I try to pip install tensorflow I get the following message

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

I am using macOS yosemitie and python 3.6

I've tried the following:

- Installing with python 3.5
- Going to pypi, downloading the wheel and using pip on that

  - In addition, also trying to use the `--use wheel` option with pip
- git cloning the tensorflow repo and installing with `tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py`

So far nothing has worked. Any insight as to why and what I could do?

Comment: Sometimes it happens due to bad internet connectivity as well!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744737/tensorflow-mac-os-gpu-support

Comment: Same problem here..

Answer (score 1):

> Note: As of version 1.2, TensorFlow no longer provides GPU support on macOS.

run the following without `-gpu`:

```
pip  install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 2.7
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
```

official instructions can be found here: [Installing TensorFlow on macOS](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac)

Comment: where do I put the `-gpu`

Comment: Also this worked when  I used `pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Comment: sorry, mistyped... I meant without gpu... TensorFlow no longer provides GPU support on macOS.